# Java script error while loading DOJO

Tags: dojo

I am using dojo.1.6 for the ui. And I dint get any java script errors in Google Chrome 19,Internet Explorer 8. The following error is occurring in Google Chrome 31,IE 10 while loading page and the dojo is not applying to the buttons.
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getAttribute'.
Please help me.

Comment: What do you expect us to do without code? Guess where the error might come from?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17400, which affected `dojo.query` in Dojo < 1.7 with newer versions of Chrome and Firefox at least.  It was fixed in [Dojo 1.6.2](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.2/), so you might want to try replacing your current 1.6.x version with that.